# mysql select of select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

Table Student

| StudentID | StudentName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

Table Book

| BookID | BookName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Book1 |
| 2 | Book2 |
| 3 | Book3 |

Table BookAssignment

| AssignID | BookID | StudentID | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-06-26 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2021-07-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2021-07-03 |

The result table should be

| StudentID | StudentName | BookCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 3 | C | 0 |

How to get the result table in one SQL execution?
Left JOIN seems not an option since it eliminates StudentID 3

Just added another DateTime column to the BookAssignment table - What is SQL syntax to query the book count over the last 7 consecutive days (even for 0 book for day count)?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use simple group by using left join between two tables:

```
select s.StudentID, s.StudentName , count(*) BookCount 
from students s
left join books b
  on s.StudentID = b.StudentID
group by s.StudentID, s.StudentName
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd left join the student table on an aggregate query of the books and use `coalesce` to fill in the zeros:

```sql
SELECT    s.StudentID, StudentName, COALESCE(cnt, 0)
FROM      student s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   StudentID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM     books
           GROUP BY StudentID) b ON s.StudentID = b.StudentID
```

Comment: Missing cnt after COUNT(*) - it works great. Thank you

Comment: @KennethN indeed, my bad. Thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*,
       (select count(*)
        from books b
        where s.StudentID = b.StudentID
       ) as bookCount
from students s;
```

This has some advantages over using a `join`/`group by` approach:

- You can trivially include all columns in the `select`.  They don't have to repeated in the `group by`.
- With an index on `books(StudentID)` this often has the best performance.
- This avoids the outer aggregation, which can kill performance.
- Adding another dimension (say the number of courses the student has) just works, without worrying about Cartesian Products.

Comment: very clean and powerful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

select s.StudentID, s.StudentName ,(select count(*) from BookAssignment b where b.studentid = s.studentid) as BookCount
from students s